# Extracting Floating Values from A String In A Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have the following dataframe, `df`:

```
name         result

AAA           4.5
BBB           UNK
CCC      less than 2.45
DDD     Men > 40: 2.5-3.5
```

The `dtypes` of the `result` column is `dtype('O')`

I need to extract the float values and filter them with a particular threshold.

I tried the following script to extract the values and change them to float:

```
df['result'] = df['result'].str.extract(r'(\d+.\d+)').astype('float')
```

However, I'm not sure if I'm getting the right output, especially when the value has a range `2.5-3.5`. In this scenario, I want the max value, `i.e. 3.5`.

Desired output:

```
name         result

AAA           4.5
CCC           2.45
DDD           3.5
```

What would be the smartest way of doing it? Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `extractall` to extract all float number occurrences, then use `max` to take only the max value.

```
>>> ext = (df.result.str.extractall(r'(\d+.\d+)')
       .astype(float)
       .unstack()
       .max(axis=1))

>>> ext
0    4.50
2    2.45
3    3.50
```

Next, you can join this back to your original dataframe. `ext` is currently a Series, so convert it to dataframe before joining using `to_frame`. If you like to drop NaN, use `inner` join and if you want to keep it, use `left` (default).

```
>>> df = df[['name']].join(ext.to_frame('result'), how='inner')
>>> df
  name  result
0  AAA    4.50
2  CCC    2.45
3  DDD    3.50
```

Comment: Thank you @emma for the help with nice explanation. Appreciate!

Comment: Hi @emma, if I want to completely remove those rows with range values, i.e. `DDD` row, how should I approach that?

Comment: is the logic is "if containing "-"?" or should be more robust logic?  If it is former, you can do `df[~df.result.str.contains('-')]`.  If you need to match with regex, check DataFrame.filter function.